# Vector input output in r

Tags: r

I have been researching and have tried a ton of different things and have been unsuccessful in trying to get this function to take vector inputs for X, td, D0, for the program. ultimately i want to see how the value of an option changes when the strike, ex dividend, and dividend amount varies, not at the same time but one at a time. this is for discrete dividends i am not considering yields. this is my first real program and have only been using r as a calculator so i am not just wet behind the ears but dripping from head to toe. i would really appreciate any help.

```
DivADJBSM<-function(S, X, rf, T,td, sigma,D0) {
values <- matrix(,3,2)
Dd<-(D0*exp(-rf*T))    #discounted dividend#
Sd<-(S-Dd)      #Stock adjusted for present value of dividends#
Xd1=(X-D0)      #Strike adjusted after dividend paid#
K=td/T      #dividend payment to terminal date impact#
SigA=(sigma*S)/(Sd)     #adjusted volatility full#
    WSig=(sigma*S)/(S-(Dd*K)) #volatility adjustment impact of payment date#

     d1 <- (log(Sd/Xd1)+(rf*T))/(SigA*sqrt(T)) +((SigA*sqrt(T))/2)
     d2 <- d1 - (SigA * sqrt(T))
     d3 <- (log(Sd/Xd1)+(rf*T))/(WSig*sqrt(T)) +((WSig*sqrt(T))/2)
     d4 <- d3 - (WSig * sqrt(T))
     d5 <- (log(S/X)+(rf*T))/(sigma*sqrt(T)) +((sigma*sqrt(T))/2)
     d6 <- d5 - (sigma * sqrt(T))

     values[1] <- (Sd)*pnorm(d1) - (Xd1)*exp(-rf*T)*pnorm(d2)
     values[4] <- (Xd1)*exp(-rf*T)*pnorm(-d2)-(Sd)*pnorm(-d1)  
     values[2] <- (Sd)*pnorm(d3) - (Xd1)*exp(-rf*T)*pnorm(d4)
     values[5] <- (Xd1)*exp(-rf*T)*pnorm(-d4)-(Sd)*pnorm(-d3)
    values[3] <- (S)*pnorm(d5) - (X)*exp(-rf*T)*pnorm(d6)
     values[6] <- (X)*exp(-rf*T)*pnorm(-d6)-(S)*pnorm(-d5)          

print("Calls COL=1, Puts COL=2, Full Vol ADJ ROW=1, Weighted Vol ROW=2, Std BSM ROW=3") 
   values
}
```

Comment: Please post the sample data using `dput` so that the code can be tested

Comment: I suspect the problem is not so much with vectorized *inputs* as with vectorized *output*.  Your `values[j]` can't take multiple items per element.  You could make `values` a list variable, but all in all mrip's solution is easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want with `lapply`.  Here's a simple example:

```
> fun<-function(x) x^2
> lapply(1:3,fun)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 9
```

If you have multiple arguments, then by default it iterates over the first argument, but you can specify which one gets iterated over by naming the rest of the arguments at the end of the `lapply` call:

```
> fun<-function(x,y,z) c(x,y^2,z^3)
> lapply(1:3,fun,2,3)
[[1]]
[1]  1  4 27

[[2]]
[1]  2  4 27

[[3]]
[1]  3  4 27

> lapply(1:3,fun,x=2,z=3)
[[1]]
[1]  2  1 27

[[2]]
[1]  2  4 27

[[3]]
[1]  2  9 27

> lapply(1:3,fun,x=2,y=3)
[[1]]
[1] 2 9 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 9 8

[[3]]
[1]  2  9 27
```

In order to use this with your function, you are going to have to rename the `X` argument, because `X` is also one of the arguments to `lapply`, which will mess things up.

Comment: thanks it worked all i had to do was change a few names around. is there something i should do differently when writing the program so that i could name vectors and have them as inputs?

Comment: Well, there's not one specific thing.  You just have to make sure while you are writing your function that the operations you use will work with vectors as inputs.  In this case, you would also have to decide what you want the output to look like, what happens if more than one vector is passed in, etc.